# Trying to add a comma in between each value of my list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a dice program that must roll the dice a certain amount of times and append those rolls to a list. I am trying to figure out how to add commas in between each item of the list. This is the code that I have so far:

```
listRolls = []

def listPrint():
    for i, item in enumerate(listRolls):
        if (i+1)%13 == 0:
            print(item)
        else:
            print(item,end=' ')
```

Comment: not a good dupe. its concattenating _strings_ not printing - you could create strings from numbers and concattenate but thats not even needed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
print(item,end=' ')
```

into

```
print(item,end=',')
```

Answer (score 3):

`print(', '.join(listRolls))`

For future reference, it's more "pythonic" (not my word) to use lower case `variable_names`, meaning your `listRolls` would then be `list_rolls`.  Your code will handle it JUST FINE, however!

Comment: I'd prefer this solution among three answers here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print your whole list in one line, komma seperated simply use

```
data = [2,3,4,5,6]

print( *data, sep=",")
```

The `*` before the list-variable will make single elements from your list (decomposing it), so the print command essentially sees:

```
print( 2,3,4,5,6 , sep=",")
```

The `sep=","` tells the print command to print all given elements with a seperator as specified instead of the default `' '`.

If you need to print, say, only 4 consecutive elements from your list on one line, then you can slice your list accordingly:

```
data = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

# slice the list in parts of length 4 and print those:
for d in ( data[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(data),4)):
    print( *d, sep=",")
```

Output:

```
2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9
10,11
```

Doku:

- [unpacking lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)
- [`print(*objects, sep=' ', ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
- [`range(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: Okay that makes sense... I’m going to revise mine and see which works best. Thank you!!